# Проблемы со структурами C++

Tags: c++, строки, struct

Есть структура с двумя параметрами: слово (`str`) и число (`cnt`; не спрашивайте зачем, это не важно). Создан массив этой структуры. Моя цель - поменять местами наборы `(str, cnt)` в этом массиве, если так окажется, что в этих наборах `cnt` равны, но по алфавиту один меньше другого. Как только ввожу новую `char s` для замены, он выдает ошибку "выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением". В чем проблема?

```
const int   WORDLEN = 80;
const int   MAXWORDS = 100;

struct Elem {
    char str[WORDLEN + 1];
    int cnt;
};

Elem list[MAXWORDS];
int last = 0;

void Letter() {
    char s[WORDLEN + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < last - 1; j++) {
            if (list[i].cnt == list[j + 1].cnt) {
                if (list[i].str > list[j + 1].str) {
                    s = list[i].str;
                    list[i].str = list[j + 1].str;
                    list[j + 1].str = s;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки, представленные как массивы `char`, непосредственно не копируются. Для этого следует использовать функции типа [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) или `strcpy_s`.

И, кстати, для сравнения **содержимого** строк (а не их указателей) следует также использовать соответствующие функции - [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, содержимое массивов в С++ никак не сравнивается простым применением оператора `>`, поэтому ваше наивное

```
if (list[i].str > list[j + 1].str)
```

уже бессмысленно. Никакого сравнения "по алфавиту" при этом не происходит. Если вам нужно сравнение "по алфавиту", то это либо `strcmp`, либо `memcmp`, либо сравнение вручную, в зависимости от того, что хранится в ваших массивах.

Во-вторых, голые массивы некопируемы операторами языка, о чем вам и говорит компилятор. Однако никто вам не запрещает копировать целые структуры

```
Elem s = list[i];
list[i] = list[j + 1];
list[j + 1] = s;
```

Также можно заметить, что `std::swap` умеет обменивать местами массивы, т.е. можно сделать просто

```
std::swap(list[i].str, list[j + 1].str);
```

В-третьих, не ясна логика работы с переменной `j`. Зачем везде упорно используется `j + 1`, когда можно было просто учесть это `+ 1` в заголовке цикла

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < last; j++)
```

а внутри цикла использовать просто `j`?